# Filter a QGIS attribute table using an attribute value from another layer

Tags: qgis, intersection, filter

I am trying to filter an attribute table in QGIS 3.22 using 'Advanced Filter (Expression)' so that the filtered features shown are only those that intersect with a value of an attribute in another layer. The layer I want to filter is a shapefile showing owners of areas of land. The layer I want to filter it by is a shape file of land uses. So, for example, the land use file contains a value 'Quarry'. I want then to filter the land owners table so that it only shows the owners that intersect with the 'Quarry' value in the land use shapefile. This then helps me to see if the land owner is likely to be a quarrying company.

I don't want to run a spatial join, both because this will take 2 days to run and because it won't help me as much as being able to visually assess each intersect.

I have tried using the expression `intersects($geometry,(get_feature( 'Land_use_ layer', 'Land_use_field', 'land_use_value')))` but it comes up with an error `'Eval Error: Cannot convert to geometry'` and I'm not sure why. Am I close?!

Answer (score 5):

Both parameters of `intersects` have to be a geometry. `get_feature` returns feature itself. You need `geometry` function to get feature's geometry.

```sql
intersects($geometry,
           geometry(
               get_feature(
                   'Land_use_layer',
                   'Land_use_field',
                   'Quarry' ) ) )
```

This solution is for Query Builder (right-click layer > Filter...)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That does work but I think it only shows the first feature in the land use layer? As I believe get_feature 'Returns the first feature of a layer matching a given attribute value.' How can I filter for all features that intersect with 'Quarry' in the other layer?

Comment: This solution is for Query Builder (right-click layer > Filter...)

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesnt work in Query builder. I get "An error occurred when executing the query.
The data provider said: OGR[3] error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected $undefined. Occurred around : intersects($geometry, geometry(get_feature"

Comment: Is another option to use the 'Overlay_intersects' function? I tried this and it accepted the function but it froze my machine!

Comment: Using expression may cause freezing QGIS if you have a huge dataset. Because every time the expression runs, it checks if the current feature's geometry intersects all geometries in the other layer. Try to run the expression after using "Create Spatial Index" tool for both layers.

Comment: The other solution would be use a script. If it is well coded, it usually runs faster than an expression.